# How to change the colour of specific arrows on a flow chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

It appears my flowchart is nonplanar (it contains a subdivided K_3,3...)

How do I colour specific arrows, so I can make it visually clearer what's going on when they inevitably cross? (by 'arrows', I mean the whole arrow as opposed to just the arrow head).

Thanks

(/how can I create a 3D flow chart?)

Comment: Please include an example of what you have done, so that we may understand better what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the color to the options to `\draw` or `\path`, such as

```
\draw[->,thick,dashed,blue]
```

or

```
\path[line,red] (a) -- (b);
```